# PHP can't write files

Tags: php, apache, file, centos

I had a Apache HTTP server on CentOS, I installed PHP (`yum install php`) and then tested a simple script that writes text in a file, so I do

```
$file = fopen($filename,"w") or die("Failure");
```

The problem is that it's always a failure, even after I did a `chown apache:apache /var/www/html/*` or a `chmod 777 *` in that directory, so anyone knows a way to understand / fix this?

EDIT : So there the problem was thath the directory itself did'nt have the chown

Comment: Can you try creating a file in the directory? That should isolate whether its a permissions issue or a problem with coding..

Comment: #1 include your code. #2 have you accounted for SELinux?

Comment: Are you creating your file and running your script in that directory or a sub-directory of `/var/www/html/`?

Comment: Use `-R` option with `chmod` and `chown` to recursively apply the mods. Yet, `777` is the worst chmod you can set. Use a more decent one like `640` on files and `750` on directories.

Comment: If you only did a chmod "in that directory", the problem is likely that there is no permission to write on "that directory". So if you are writing to `/var/www/html/` and failed, check the permissions on `/var/www/html/`. Changing the permission on a file in the directory will only help if the file already exists. Changing the permission of the directory you are writing to will allow you to create a new file.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to say what it is without the actual error message from PHP.

Have a look at this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp

Long story short, create and set a custom error handler, like so:

```
<?php
//error handler function
function customError($errno, $errstr) {
  echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr";
}

//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError");

//trigger error
$file = fopen($filename,"w")
?>
```

In your case, I think that in order for it to be able to create new files in the given directory, you would want to add a '-R' flag to chmod or chown and call it on the directory itself rather than the children -- that way, if PHP has to create the file, it has permissions to do so.

EDIT: Just curious about why this has a downvote -- what is the "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."?  I told the OP to examine the error messages and set their permissions in a properly recursive fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Change w mode to w+ - it will allow php to create file if it's not exist.

```
$file = fopen($filename,"w+") or die("Failure");
```

Comment: PHP will attempt to create it in mode w.  The difference between w and w+ is that w+ opens for both reading and writing.